# Push Data to Nifi Flow using apache spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-nifi

I want to get data from nifi flow to spark and do some stuff. After that I want to send result again to nifi flow.

This is my nifi flow to send data to spark using output ports.

[image]

To get data from Nifi flow I wrote the below function.

```
def process() ={

    val schema =
      StructType(
        Seq(
          StructField(name = "ID", dataType = StringType, nullable = false),
          StructField(name = "Client_Name", dataType = StringType, nullable = false),
          StructField(name = "Due_Date", dataType = StringType, nullable = false),
          StructField(name = "Score", dataType = StringType, nullable = false)
        )
      )

    val config =
      new SiteToSiteClient
      .Builder()
      .url("http://localhost:8090/nifi")
      .portName("Data For Spark")
        .buildConfig()


    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("NiFi-Spark Streaming example")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

    val packetStream = ssc.receiverStream(new NiFiReceiver(config, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY))

    val file = packetStream.map(dataPacket => new String(dataPacket.getContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))


    file.foreachRDD(rdd => {

      val data = spark.createDataFrame(rdd
                                              .filter(!_.contains("ID,Client_Name,Due_Date,Score"))
                                              .map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(",").toSeq)), schema)

      data.show(100)
      val id = data.select("ID")

    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()



  }
```

The final result of above function is `id` dataframe. I want to send that result to nifi flow. I don't want to write that result as a file to some destination and get to nifi flow using `getFile` processor.

How can I send the final result to nifi flow?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting approach.

Have you considered introducing a brokering service such as Apache Kafka? This can be used both as a source and as a sink in your Apache Spark application and the integration is out of the box. You can also follow the official guide here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html. The guide describes a flow using the relatively new Apache Spark Structured Streaming.

Then on Apache NiFi you can use the ConsumeKafkaRecord processor to consume from the same topic being used as a sink in your Apache Spark application. You can also make use of the PublishKafkaRecord processor if you wish to refactor your application to make use of Apache Kafka as a source as well rather than relying on Apache NiFi sockets directly.

Update: If you absolutely must write directly to Apache NiFi, using Apache Spark Structured Streaming you can extend the `ForeachWriter` class (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter) to implement your own custom sink.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. But the problem is I can't use Kafka here. What I want is send the result to nifi flow directly, like I pull data from nifi to spark process.

Comment: I went through the library source code and this does not seem possible unfortunately. May I ask why you cannot make use of Apache Kafka?

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution you might want to look into if you really must write back directly to Apache NiFi.

Comment: Because for the overall process we don't use Kafka here. That's why I want to write directly nifi. I'll will try with your updated answer. Thank you so mush for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/). That way you will treat NiFi as a simple REST service. Personally, I would prefer some message bus involved between Spark and NiFi but if it is not possible for your use case then you can try if that works for you.